# Perl code editor with class explorer

Tags: perl, editor, geany

I setup Geany now, it's fine, but code navigation panel is very simple (tag-based):

```
+Package
    MyPackage1
    MyPackage2
+Functions
  MyPackage1Func1
  MyPackage1Func2
  MyPackage2Func1
  MyPackage2Func2
```

Whether there is editor with perl object model explorer support?
Like that:

```
+Package
    +MyPackage1
    +Functions
      MyPackage1Func1
    MyPackage1Func2 
    +MyPackage2
    +Functions
      MyPackage2Func1
      MyPackage2Func2
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Komodo](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide&ei=gj5CTpikMMPpOfKUzb4J&usg=AFQjCNHggx-vfbPeQ2rRa_Qx6rvXuU_NfQ) or its free version [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit).

Here is the default Komodo code browser view :

[image: Komodo default code view]

Comment: It's nice, but why XML::LibXML::Document is the sublevel of XML::LibXML::Node? It's one level structures, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at M-x imenu-tree in Emacs.